# Never returns from QQmlApplicationEngine.load()

Tags: qt, qml

So this is not a real problem, I just discovered some weird behaviour that I can't find an explanation for.

I'm running my QML application from Qt with the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qDebug() << "Loading QML file";  
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("../qml/main.qml")));

    qDebug() << "Executing application"; // This is never printed
    return app.exec();
}
```

As far as I know this is pretty standard and it works completely fine. But it turns out that it never gets to the point where `app.exec()` is called. I even tried to remove `app.exec()` and just return 0. And it still works.

Does anyone know why that is? According to the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#exec) event handling should not work if `app.exec()` has not been called.

Comment: Are you sure you are debugging it correctly? Are you using a debug build of Qt?

Comment: which version are you using ?